add to all existing "items" on tag-style field
I have a modal, where an admin can add users to multiple accounts, by typing in a field to trigger the type-ahead suggestions. They then select the desired account, and it adds it to the screen in a small blue section similar to how assigned tags appear, along with an "add another"
My challenge is that some admins manage a high number of accounts, and may want to add a specific person to "all" accounts - much quicker than doing this process, and to avoid a modal showing 100 account pills. My two thoughts were to allow "all accounts" as an option in the field - but that's a hidden feature, or I could simply have a text link to the right side for this use case.
What are other proven ways to achieve this, or have I got a good solution?
I attached an image to illustrate


add to all is OK and it's the most common pattern for this purpose. So this is the lesser of your problems. The thing is: what if they want to add all BUT one account (or two or whatever)? Also, managing 100 accounts in the space of a modal seems a bit problematic

Yeah, it's a modal that worked until added functionality was required. We may have to transition to a full page in near future. Are there any examples that cover the scenario you described - Adding to all but a small number?

When it comes to selecting a large number of items, select fields don't offer the best user experience.
A better solution:

a scrollable list of items that can be selected / deselected one by one
2 buttons ("select all" and "deselect all") that can toggle the entire selection
a search box for filtering the items
a count indicator showing selected items vs total items

Items can also be arranged on 2 columns when there is enough space.
Here is an example of such UI component:

